# Python Extend List when declaring list

Tags: python

In Javascript, I can do something like this

```
let list = [1, 2, 3]
let list2 = [4, 5, 6, ...list]
```

And the resulting list would be [4,5,6,1,2,3]

Is there a way to do this in Python without having to call `extend()` or using `+=` after declaring the list?

Comment: `list2 = [4, 5, 6, *list]`

Comment: BTW, try to avoid declaring a variable name that can shadow built-in function: `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional unpacking generalizations of [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) (added in Python 3.5) allows the following syntax:

```
list2 = [4, 5, 6, *list]
```

The elements of the first `list` are unpacked, one after another, in the same order they appear in the original `list`.

Prior to 3.5, the best solution is just:

```
list2 = [4, 5, 6] + list
```

which is still a one-liner, but has to construct the temporary `list` first, then concatenate the two of them and throw away the temporary.